# accessing each frame of video and processing it

Tags: c++, opencv, live-streaming

I am trying to write a program which stores each frame of a video file as an image using `OPENCV` with CPP. I have achieved that with `ffmpeg` and `mplayer`. I want to get it using `OPENCV`. Can anyone help? Is there any other function to store an image to a file other than `IMWRITE()`?

Is there any function in `OPENCV` to get the live streaming of video which is available at a particular port of a device and process it in real time ? i.e to store each frame of stream as an image?
Can anyone help me out?

thanks in advance..:)

Comment: why is `cv::imwrite` not ok for you?

Comment: it copied only the last frame. i want to save all the frames as image1.jpg,image2.jpg....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

saving all images with increasing numbered filenames, this works for me:

```
const char* videofilename = "StopMoti2001.mpeg";
cv::VideoCapture cap(videofilename); // open a video file
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if succeeded
{
    std::cout << "file " << videofilename << " not found or could not be opened" << std::endl;
    return;
}

cv::namedWindow("output");

unsigned long counter = 0;

cv::Mat frame;
// read frames until end of video:
while(cap.read(frame))
{

    // display frame
    cv::imshow("output", frame); cv::waitKey(25);   // remove this line if you don't need the live output


    // adjust the filename by incrementing a counter
    std::stringstream filename (std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
    filename << "image" <<  counter++ << ".jpg";

    std::cout << "writing " << filename.str().c_str() << " to disk" << std::endl;

    // save frame to file: image0.jpg, image1.jpg, and so on...
    cv::imwrite(filename.str().c_str(),frame);

}
```

Comment: thanks..i tried the program but i am getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) error

Comment: is any image displayed or any file written? The `for(;;)` isn't so good because for video files (different from live cameras) there will be an end of the file somewhere ;)

Comment: can you post your code snippet where you used `cv::imwrite` that only saved the last image? i'll try to modify it to your needs.

Comment: i had just used imwrite("filename", frame)

Comment: can you try to run the updated code and tell me what console output you get?

Comment: i got the video output and images:) thanks a lot :)    can u help me in getting live stream from a particular port of a device. the device is connected to the laptop using wifi.

Comment: i tried using "ip_address:port number" in VideoCapture method but i am not getting anything...

Comment: sorry, no idea about that.
If my answer helped you to save all the images, feel free to upvote (don't need to accept the answer yet).

Comment: do u know y does the segmentation fault occurs? i am getting a segmentation fault when i try to capture frames from camera(live streaming) after some time..i.e the loop is nt running as an infinite loop

Comment: So in the beginning everything runs nice but after some time it crashes? Maybe the webcam doesnt deliver correct images? Can you add `std::cout<<frame.cols<<std::endl;` before the imshow and tell me the last output?

Comment: and can you add a `std::cout` after the loop, or are you very sure that the error occurs inside the loop?